# Problems with the getImageList call

Tags: modx, getresource

It seems that my getImageList call in my ModX website doesn't work. I've got a template calling to the slider chunk. In the slider chunk is the following code:

```
<div id="slider">   <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns nopad">
      <div class="slidercontainer">
        <ul class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-auto-height="calc" data-cycle-slides="> li" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-next=".slidercontainer .next" data-cycle-prev=".slidercontainer .prev" data-cycle-swipe="true" data-cycle-log="false">
          [[!getImageList? &tvname=`sliderMIGX` &tpl=`slideTpl` &limit=`0` &where=`{"status:=":"1"}`]]
        </ul>
      </div>             
    </div>   </div> </div>
```

Only the middle part (the getimagelist call) should be important though. If i add some regular text in the same UL as the getImageList call it shows it so i know it has nothing to do with the slider call or styling for that matter. I'm doubtful about the packages i have installed though. I've got an example site (which already has the slider running) but i can't seem to copy the code i need. Is there something obvious i'm missing with my call or do i need specific packages to get this to work ( i have MigX and getResources installed). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the most obvious by making sure you're supposed to see results. Are there any slides with "status=1"? Try removing the &where clause and see if it works without it.
Make sure you're not supposed to call the TV with a prefix, if you're looping this through a getResources for example.

Comment: Removing the &where call shows all the images but in a non-slider fashion. It just lists them.

Comment: I'm grateful for your help, my company got this part done by another company we are connected to (it just wouldn't be profitable enough to put more time in it). I'll post the solution when they finish it.